# How did wolfram alpha reduce this second order homogeneous recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a recurrence relation as follows:

$$ d(n+2) = -(n+2)^2d(n) - (2n+5)d(n+1)$$

Setting `n=0` and generating a few coefficients gives

$ d(0) = a$
$ d(1) = b $
$ d(2) = - 4a - 5b $
$ d(3) = 28a + 26b $
$ d(4) = - 188a - 154b $
$ d(5) = 1368a + 1044b $
$ d(6) = - 11016a - 8028b $

It turns out the coefficients of `a` and `b` are both listed in the OEIS ([a](http://oeis.org/A045406), [b](http://oeis.org/A001705)). Both mention being a Harmonic number times factorial, but the connection doesn't seem very rigorous (e.g., "If we eliminate the first term and set a(0)=3, then a(0)..a(12) = (-1)^(n+1)*n!*(2*H(n)-3)..where H(n) is the n'th harmonic number").

Given the initial conditions `d(0)=a, d(1)=b` Wolfram alpha gives

$$ d(n) = -(-1)^n \Gamma(n+2) ((2 a+b) H_{n+1}-3 a-b) $$

I'm trying to get from the recurrence equation to the slightly more accessible form with Harmonic numbers, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was answered in [Marko Petkovsek's Thesis](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~singer/CIMPA/petkovsek_hyper.pdf) (who also implemented the algorithm in mathematica). Presumably (but not certainly), a more expository account is given in Petkovsek/Zeilberger's A=B (which is available for free).

**EDIT** The Petkovsek paper discusses higher order linear difference equations too.

Comment: It looks like _A=B_ has everything I need. Excellent resource.

Comment: Do you know any papers that discuss $3^{rd}$ order recurrences with polynomials coefficients?

Comment: @MillardoPeacecraft Yes, same paper, see edit.